# Using template literal in jsx doesn't work

Tags: jsx

In a React app I want to render

```
"<td className="RuleRow-name">{{`rulesD.${this.props.name}`}}</td>"
```

So, if this.props.name is "john" it should render the value of rulesD.john.

I've tried composing the template literal in a few different ways but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of a template literal is a string, while you are trying to get property `name`, where `name` can be any string, for example "john". To do so, use brackets notation to get the value of the prop `name` in object `rulesD`:

```
<td className="RuleRow-name">{rulesD[this.props.name]}</td>
```

Example

```js
const rulesD = { john: 1, jill: 2 }

const Demo = ({ name }) => (
  <div>{rulesD[name]}</div>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Demo name="john" />
    <Demo name="jill" />
  </div>,
  root
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help. Eventually there was another error in the code that prevented it from working so I went another route but I think your answer is right, althought I haven't tried it.

Answer (score -1):

it should be like

```js
<td>{`rulesD.${this.props.name}`}</td>
```

Comment: I've tried it but it renders rulesD.(the props name). So instead of accessing the object value "rulesD.props.name" and therefore rendering it , it treats the "rulesD." part as a string.  I've tried logging rulesD.(the props name) and it logs well.